# Which Android component to use for orchestration (automatism)?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I'm just starting out with jetpack compose, and beyond that with android too, and I often have trouble knowing which of the existing components to use in which situation. More specifically, my problem concerns the need to automatically manage screen changes during a specific process (flow).

Basically, I'm wondering how I could implement a component that would allow me to track the status of a multi-stage operation and, depending on the current stage, automatically (without any interaction on the part of the user) direct the user to screens where he can provide information.

For the moment I've tried to do this with a viewmodel, but I also have the problem that some of my pages are in compose and others via activities. So I'm having trouble launching the latter via the viewModel (which I don't think is advisable).

Is an activity to do what I've described above sufficient/adapted? Please note that I use navcontroller navigation in the application and that most of my pages are composable functions.

Comment: Just make each flow a graph: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/nested-graphs

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).